# Proper usage of HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, having-clause

I am working with MySQL and my goal is to `UPDATE` only fields in a table that satisfy specific condition. Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE tbl_money AS m 
SET m.amount = m.amount + (SELECT SUM( b.bn_ppd )
                           FROM tbl_emp AS e
                           LEFT JOIN tbl_bonuses AS b 
                              ON b.bn_id = e.bn_id
                           WHERE m.u_id = e.u_id
                           HAVING COUNT(e.u_id) > 0
                           GROUP BY e.u_id LIMIT 1)
```

With the above I would like to add on the current amount the sum of bonuses that an employee has and only to the employees who exist in `tbl_emp`. As it is, I am getting an error message:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY o.user_id LIMIT 1)' at line 7

Without `HAVING` clause, the system updates amount of all employees but those who don't have any bonus, it just resets the amount to 0 (even if they have an amount already). To those who have bonus, is working fine.

Any ideas? What is the proper way to use `HAVING`?

UPDATE:

```
tbl_bonuses
-----------
bn_id | bn_ppd
1       5
2       2
3       4
4       10

tbl_emp
-------
emp_id | u_id | bn_id | ...
1       30      2
2       30      3
3       31      1

tbl_money
---------
m_id | u_id | amount
1      30     100
2      31     56
3      32     35
```

After the update the desired result should be

```
    tbl_money
    ---------
    m_id | u_id | amount
    1      30     106
    2      31     57
    3      32     35
```

However, I am getting this result,

```
    tbl_money
    ---------
    m_id | u_id | amount
    1      30     106
    2      31     57
    3      32     0
```

Comment: `HAVING` appears after the `GROUP BY` and before the `LIMIT`

Comment: Reorder HAVING and GROUP BY clauses.

Comment: For starters, the `HAVING` clause goes after `GROUP BY` not before...

Comment: Awesome, thank you guys. Unfortunately, even if it is working, the result is not as expected.

Comment: @PanayiotisNicolaou Can you edit your post with the some sample data and then the desired result of the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `UPDATE` statement:

```
update tbl_money m
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT e.u_id, SUM( b.bn_ppd ) BonusPaid
  FROM tbl_emp AS e
  LEFT JOIN tbl_bonuses AS b 
    ON b.bn_id = e.bn_id
  GROUP BY e.u_id
  HAVING COUNT(e.u_id) > 0
) e
  on m.u_id = e.u_id
set m.amount = m.amount + e.BonusPaid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3efa9/1)

Comment: I am on first steps in MySQL as you can see. Thank you, I will keep improve myself :)

Comment: @PanayiotisNicolaou You are welcome, we all have to start somewhere. :)

Answer (score 2):

HAVING needs to go after the GROUP BY clause